# Which is the more efficient threadsafe queue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, queue

There is a simple task: many threads call `MyClass.add()` function, and a thread tries to serve them.
My question: which is the better or more efficient solution?

1st approach: with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

```
@Singleton
public class myClass {

    List<myType> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<myType>();
    boolean isRunning = false;

    //this is called from many threads
    public void add(myType x){
        list.add(x);
    }


    //this is called from 1 thread
    public void start(){
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            myType curr = list.remove(0);

            //do something with curr...
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

2nd approach with simple locks:

```
@Singleton
public class myClass {

    List<myType> list = new ArrayList<myType>();
    boolean isRunning = false;
    private final Lock _mutex = new ReentrantLock(true);

    //this is called from many threads
    public void add(myType x){
        _mutex.lock();
        list.add(x);
        _mutex.unlock();
    }


    //this is called from 1 thread
    public void start(){
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            _mutex.lock();
            myType curr = list.remove(0);
            _mutex.unlock();

            //do something with curr...
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

3rd approach: with `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

```
@Singleton
public class myClass {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<myType> list = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<myType>();
    boolean isRunning = false;

    //this is called from many threads
    public void add(myType x){
        list.add(x);
    }


    //this is called from 1 thread
    public void start(){
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            //list cannot be empty at this point: other threads can't remove any items 
            myType curr = list.poll();

            //do something with curr...
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

And this was the original wrong solution. I don't know why it gave sometimes (>100 threads) `ConcurrentModificationException` (despite of iterator and "synchronized"):

```
@Singleton
public class myClass {

    List<myType> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<myType>());
    boolean isRunning = false;

    //this is called from many threads
    public void add(myType x){
        synchronized(list) {
            list.add(x);
        }
    }


    //this is called from 1 thread
    public void start(){
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;

        for (ListIterator<myType> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            myType curr = iter.next();

            //do something with curr...

            synchronized(list) {
                iter.remove(); //sometime it gives ConcurrentModificationException!
            }
        }
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what your objectives are.

Comment: Seems like a quick performance wrapper that forks X threads that make Y queue transactions is in order.  Go for it!

Comment: Your original wrong solution doesn't prevent other threads from modifying the list inside the loop before the `synchronized` block.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that `Collections.synchronized*()` are useless.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Comment: @Adam Arold: to be threadsafe, memory-friendly and fast. :)

Comment: How many items per second do through the queue, and how much time the server thread spends to serve an item?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: worst case is 100 items arrive into the queue per second, and it takes 4s to serve one of them. But most of the time there is no activity in the queue. Thanks!

Comment: @steve with this numbers, the time spend to put/get items in the queue is insignificant compared to the time to handle items. Chose most compact, reliable and readable solution (say, BlockingLinkedQueue) and forget about efficiency. Start to think about it only when rate approaches 1 million per second.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: thanks, i decided to do it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is: the one that fits your problem best.

The lock variant is slowing everything down a lot, because all threads a put on hold if they enter the lock part, even though there is no need for it (if there are 5 elements, 5 threads can poll them simultaneously, only the 6th has to wait). This solution however is good, if you have a singular resource that can never be shared, like a network connection or a file.

The CopyOnWriteArrayList is the best solution, if your thread rarely writes but very often reads. There is a much higher cost associated with the write, which is compensated with the much faster read (compared to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue). But your code primarily writes, so this isn't a good solution for you.

The ConcurrentLinkedQueue is the best solution, if the amount of reads and writes are about equal, hence the name Queue. So it should fit your case the best.

In addition you have a serious error in your code:

```
while (!list.isEmpty()) {
  myType curr = list.poll();
```

The list just guarantees that each call is done atomically, but your code is not automatically thread-safe just because you use it. In this example the list could have already been modified between the `isEmpty()` and the `poll()`, so it could have 1 element on the isEmpty() call, but then none once you poll. This is handled gracefully by the ConcurrentLinkedQueue by returning null, but not by your code. So the correct form would be:

```
myType curr;
while ((curr = list.poll()) != null) {
```

As the poll is an atomic - and therefore thread-safe - call, it will either return an element or not. What happens before and what happens afterwards is undefined thanks to threading, but you can be sure that this single call (which does a lot more in the background) will always work perfectly.

The same is true for your `remove(0)` call, it can throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the last element has been removed by another thread in between.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code.
I chose ConcurrentLinkedQueue. :)

To the error: in this case only one thread can enter function start() (boolean isRunning protects it), so it is impossible that the size of the list is smaller after IsEmpty() and before poll(). (as i commented it in the code). But in general you have right.

Comment: Your `isRunning` protects against nothing, for the same reason. ;)
And if you do not define it as volatile, each thread will work based on its own local copy anyways. An AtomicBoolean can help you here.

Comment: oh, i forgot to say that this class is a singleton bean. So isRunning protects.